# Accessing further data

Tags: laravel, vue.js

So I am accessing an external API and I am trying to display this data

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yop0I.png

and everything was fine so far as you can see

https://i.stack.imgur.com/L3hXq.png

using this code

```
        <tr v-for="cv_output in cv_outputs" :key="cv_output.id">
                <td>{{ 'teste' }}</td>
                <td>{{ cv_output['id'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ cv_output['last-modified-date'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ cv_output['output-category']['value'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ cv_output['output-category']['code'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ cv_output['output-type']['value'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ cv_output['output-type']['code'] }}</td>
                <td>{{ cv_output['other-output'] }}</td>
```

but as soon as I try to go further such as

```
 {{ cv_output ['other-output']['title'] }}
```

the data stops displaying in the table and in the console i get the following:

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'title' of null

which doesn't make any sense I think. Any idea why?

Controller method:

```
public function getRemoteOutputs()
{
$science = Auth::user()->science_id;

$client = new Client(['headers' => ['Accept' => 'application/json']]);

$request = $client->get(
    'https://url_to_the_api/'.$science.'/degree',
    [
        'auth'          => ['client', 'secret'],
    ]

);

$data = $request->getBody()->getContents();

return $data;
}
```

Comment: how are you returning the data to your view?  maybe post the controller method used

Comment: This happens if some of the records do not have `other-output` field in it.  so other-output[anything] will result in null error. So you should first add check to see if cv_output['other-output'] is not null.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I @Helpinghand is correct, one of the records is missing `other-output`.

Try:

```
<td>
    <span v-if="cv_output['output-type']">{{ cv_output['output-type']['title'] }}</span>
    <span v-else>No Output Type Title</span>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{{ cv_output ['other-output'] ? cv_output ['other-output']['title']: ''}}
```

This will return the other-output->title if it exists, if not it should return nothing without error. (you can put whatever you want in the single quotes there if you want something like 'not available' as default)

Comment: I think he's doing it on Vue and not blade

Comment: `<td>{{ cv_output['other-output'] }}</td>` looks like blade to me

Comment: yeah i am doing it on Vue ahahah

Comment: did you tried my updated version?  just liked the v-if v-else option better ?